# Checking if pressed key is an alphabet or space in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have implemented a custom `QTextEdit` class in which I am overiding the `keyPressEvent` method.

I want to check if the key that was pressed is among the following:
1. Capital alphabets
2. Lowercase alphabets
3. Space

If my function declaration is something like:

```py
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
```

I could do something like:

```py
if event.key() in (
    QtCore.Qt.Key_A,
    QtCore.Qt.Key_B,
    QtCore.Qt.Key_C,
    QtCore.Qt.Key_D,
    ....
    ....
```

And so on.

How would I loop through these values? And how will I access the actual character that is pressed? I want to create a string of the keys pressed as long as they are alphabets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [build in string methods (eg isalpha())](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string) and [QKeyEvent.text()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#text)

```
s = event.text()
if s == ' ':
    print(s+' is space')
elif s.isalpha():
    if s.isupper():
        print(s+' is upper')
    else:
        print(s+' is lower')
else:
    print(s+' is something else')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. `event.key()` is just a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Please post and describe your answer for other people that have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Okay @Jonas has a good answer and depending on what you trying to do you do not have to ever loop through a list you can simple check to see if it is **IN** a list;

```
myList = [Qt.Key_A,Qt.Key_B,Qt.Key_C,... Qt.Key_Z]

if event.text() in myList:
   print("In My List")
```